# Jersey @Path not working in Jetty+servlet

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

I am failing to get the combination of Jetty + servlet + Jersey working. Here are my steps:

**1. pom.xml**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**2. web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" metadata-complete="false" version="3.1">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>org.example.MyApplication</servlet-name>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>org.example.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**3. sources**

```
package org.example;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("org.example");
    }
}

package org.example;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    public String get() {
        return "{\"hello\": 1337}";
    }
}
```

I deploy the WAR, created by executing `mvn clean compile package`, by copying it to the `web-apps` directory. Accessing the following URL returns my hardcoded JSON:

```
http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources
{"hello": 1337}
```

Now, I change the `@Path` in my resource:

```
@Path("/bla")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    public String get() {
        return "{\"hello\": 1337}";
    }
}
```

Now, none of the following URLs seem to work:

```
http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/bla
http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bla
http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources
http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/bla/
...
```

I tried several combinations, but I can't get it working.

Comment: Hi, Jetty philosophy is about to have a webapp deployed to a port. So you will have a webapp packaged as a single JAR. Why do you want to hotdeploy, can you tell us exactly what do you want to do, I would be easier to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I'll create a new question with more detailed info.

Comment: No need to create a new question, just edit this one.

Comment: I updated this question instead. I also changed the title to be more specific.

Comment: With how your project is set up, just comment out the whole web.xml and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your **web.xml**. This will enable package scanning of jersey and so will scan your package `org.example`.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Services</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.example
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Services</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here you can see a fully working example (defined for tomcat) but I already ported it successfully on jetty.

https://github.com/DominikAngerer/java-GsonJerseyProvider/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

Here is also a little bootstrapping help - It uses Jersey for the API Part with jetty - it also has a nice tutorial which would help you a lot!
https://github.com/amacoder/demo-restWS-spring-jersey-jpa2-hibernate

Comment: I got it working! I'll updated my question. I am not sure if this is expected behaviour or not, but it seems like a bug to me. I'll explain.

Comment: Thank you for pasting your web.xml. Before your edit, you had `/*` for `url-pattern`, so I tried that out. And it worked.

Comment: <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>

Comment: Ah :) Glad to her that it worked - if this answer is ok for you - feel free to accept it. I also changed it to /resources/* so it will be under /resources as base ;)

Comment: But that's the point. If you use `/resources/*`, nothing seems to work. Only `/*` seems to work. I have no idea why.

Comment: hm - I will get this a quick research - would be really strange

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html
Point: 6.3 - we definitely got it right. Do you got a bitbucket repo for your project so I can dig a little bit deeper?

Comment: I found it! I had `/resources`, which does not work. If you use `/resources/*`, it also works!

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, the links you provided are VERY useful to me. I certainly will accept your answer once I have enough points (I just subscribed to SO). Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear that we also found the real issue on it and it's not a strange sideeffect of something else ;) So - welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to be here.